# Optimizing a website for different resolutions

Tags: html, css

Iv'e been trying to figure this out for the last few days. Iv'e been leaning HTML and CSS for about a month now so i'm still quite new. In CSS I have position set to absolute with all positions in percentages. Should I write different CSS documents for different resolutions? At the moment I'm basing everything off of 1920 X 1080. From what I understand I need something like a responsive layout but I cant seem to figure out how to get there. I did learn on Codecademy where I made the airbnb page and that seems to adjust itself to different resolutions very well. Iv'e looked over that so I think it might just be something i'm missing.
Thanks!

If you run the code below in 1080p it will look fine whereas any lower it jumbles up all over the place.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/*start of header*/

.header {
  background: #8A0808;
}
.nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline;
}
.nav a {
  color: #E6E6E6;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-left: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*end of header*/

/*start of central box*/

.centralbox {
  width: 65%;
  height: 150%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 6%;
  left: 17.5%;
  background-color: #151515;
}
/*end of central box*/

/*start of logo*/

.logo {
  width: 22%;
  height: 16%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7%;
  left: 21%;
}
/*end of logo*/

/*start of h1*/

.h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 42.5%;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
/*end of h1*/

/*start of introduction1*/

.introduction1 {
  color: #E6E6E6;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  left: 21%;
  top: 27%;
  width: 58%;
}
/*end of introduction1*/

/*start of main picture*/

.mainimage {
  background-color: #585858;
  position: absolute;
  top: 34%;
  left: 21%;
  width: 42%;
  height: 42%;
}
.boxextension {
  width: 16%;
  height: 42%;
  background-color: #585858;
  position: absolute;
  top: 34%;
  left: 63%;
}
/*end of main picture*/

/*start of h2*/

.h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 62%;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
/*end of h2*/

/*start of introduction2*/

.introduction2 {
  color: #E6E6E6;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  width: 16%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 41%;
  left: 62%;
}
/*end of introduction2*/

/*start of table*/

.AG9S Table {
  width: 20%;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 78%;
  left: 21%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #000000;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.AG9S Table td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 7px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #E6E6E6;
}
.AG9S Table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #8A0808;
}
.AG9S Table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #2E2E2E;
}
.AG9S Table tr:first-child td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
.AG9S Table tr:first-child td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
.AG9S Table tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.AG9S Table tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
/*end of table*/

/*start of infotable1*/

.infotable Table {
  width: 30%;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 78%;
  left: 42%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #000000;
}
.infotable Table td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 7px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #E6E6E6;
}
.infotable Table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #8A0808;
}
.infotable Table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #2E2E2E;
}
.infotable Table tr:first-child td:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}
.infotable Table tr:first-child td:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
.infotable Table tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.infotable Table tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
/*end of infotable1*/

/*start of h3*/

.h3 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 42%;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
/*end of h3*/

/*start of introduction 3*/

.introduction3 {
  color: #E6E6E6;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: 96%;
  left: 42%;
  width: 30%;
}
/*end of introduction 3*/

/*start of h4*/

.h4 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 102%;
  left: 42%;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
/*end of h4*/

/*start of introduction 4*/

.introduction4 {
  color: #E6E6E6;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: 108%;
  left: 42%;
  width: 30%;
}
/*end of introduction 4*/

/*start of h5*/

.h5 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 117%;
  left: 42%;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
/*end of h5*/

/*start of introduction 5*/

.introduction5 {
  color: #E6E6E6;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: 123%;
  left: 42%;
  width: 30%;
}
/*end of introduction 5*/

/* start of menu*/

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 2%;
}
/*end of menu*/

/*start of footer*/

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150%;
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 30px 0;
}
.footer p {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
/*end of footer*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</title>

  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='testcss.css' />
</head>

<body background="http://i.imgur.com/EUCIQ9x.png">
  <!--start of header-->
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#"> Lorem </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Home </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> Stuff </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> This </a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"> That </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end of header-->
  <!--start of central box-->
  <div class="centralbox">
  </div>
  <!--end of central box-->
  <!--start of h1-->
  <div class="h1">
    <h1> Overview </h1> 
  </div>
  <!--end of h1-->
  <!--start of spec table 1-->
  <div class="AG9S">
    <ul>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>13</td>
          <td>14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>15</td>
          <td>16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>17</td>
          <td>18</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>22</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>24</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>25</td>
          <td>26</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>28</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>
            <li>30</li>
            <li>31</li>
            <li>32</li>
            <li>33</li>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--end of table 1-->
  <!--start of logo-->
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://git-scm.com/images/logos/downloads/Git-Logo-Black.png" width="100%" height="100%">
  </div>
  <!--end of logo-->
  <!--start of introduction1-->
  <div class="introduction1">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, facilisi similique ex duo. Id qui dico nostrud pericula, usu nemore tractatos mediocritatem id.
    </p>
  </div>
  <!--end of introduction1-->
  <!--start of image-->
  <div class="mainimage">
    <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/a/2/Y/Q/y/8/mustache-no-background.svg" height="100%" width="100%">
  </div>
  <div class="boxextension">
  </div>
  <!--end of image-->
  <!--start of introduction2-->
  <!--start of h2-->
  <div class="h2">
    <h2>Lorem</h2> 
  </div>
  <!--end of h2-->
  <div class="introduction2">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, facilisi similique ex duo. Id qui dico nostrud pericula, usu nemore tractatos mediocritatem id. Eum mazim utamur at, eu stet atqui eligendi nec. Ut vel cibo iriure.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, facilisi similique ex duo. Id qui dico nostrud pericula,
    </p>
  </div>
  <!--end of introduction2-->
  <!--start of infotable-->
  <div class="infotable">
    <ul>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>8</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!--end of infotable1-->
  <!--start of introduction 3-->
  <!--start of h3-->
  <div class="h3">
    <h2>Lorem</h2>
  </div>
  <!--end of h3-->
  <div class="introduction3">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, facilisi similique ex duo. Id qui dico nostrud pericula, usu nemore tractatos mediocritatem id. Eum mazim utamur at, eu stet atqui eligendi nec. Ut vel cibo iriure.
    </p>
  </div>
  <!--end of introduction 3-->
  <!--start of introduction 4-->
  <!--start of h4-->
  <div class="h4">
    <h2>Ipsum</h2>
  </div>
  <!--end of h4-->
  <div class="introduction4">
    <P>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, facilisi similique ex duo. Id qui dico nostrud pericula, usu nemore tractatos mediocritatem id. Eum mazim utamur at, eu stet atqui eligendi nec. Ut vel cibo iriure. Illud delenit adipisci mea in. Quo et aperiam temporibus consequuntur,
      sit ne quem eirmod pertinax.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    </p>
  </div>
  <!--end of introduction 4-->
  <!--startof h5-->
  <div class="h5">
    <h2>Dolor</h2>
  </div>
  <!--end of h6-->
  <!--start of introduction 6-->
  <div class="introduction5">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, facilisi similique ex duo. Id qui dico nostrud pericula, usu nemore tractatos mediocritatem id. Eum mazim utamur at, eu stet atqui eligendi nec. Ut vel cibo iriure. Illud delenit adipisci mea in. Quo et aperiam temporibus consequuntur,
      sit ne quem eirmod pertinax.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
    </p>
  </div>
  <!--end of introduction 6-->
  <!--start of menu-->
  <div class="menu">
    <select onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
      <option value="#">Lorem</option>
      <option value="https://www.youtube.com/">Ipsum</option>
      <option value="#">Dolor</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <!--end of menu-->
  <!--start of footer-->
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <p>&copy; blahblah 2015</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end of footer-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think you're off to a good start, but while you say you're doing everything in percentages, there still are things in pixels. The `width: 640px;` at the top for instance. That won't make for good responsiveness! Maybe you should try with some simple designs first.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should go for something like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/). And which will manage most of responsive things instead of writing too many `media queries` and css.

If any thing is not manageable with bootstrap then write `media queries` for that specific case.

Comment: These media queries are very handy but they do take up a lot of space so ill definitely have a look at bootstrap. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `media queries` along with % width/height to give your site a fluid responsive layout.

Example:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) { <!-- Desktop -->
    .menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20%;
        left: 5%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) { <!--Mobile-->
    .menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10%;
        left: 2%;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what with the widths between 480 and 992px? Neither desktop nor mobile?

Comment: The above is just an example of how media queries work @MrLister

Comment: You'll "obviously" have to define a media query for the dimensions between that too.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

To add to Andrew Laydem’s answer, remember that the browser processes the media queries in a sequential way. Which means that if second media query matches the condition, it will be processed too. For example:

```
.menu { /* Mobile */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 640px) { /* Tablet */
    .menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10%;
        left: 2%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) { /* Desktop */
    .menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20%;
        left: 5%;
    }
}
```

In the above example, if current screen width is 1440px then each set of rules will apply on top of each other (hence ruling out previous one.) But if the resolution is say 800px then only first two will be processed (and second one will stay in effect. (Correcting the way comments should be written in CSS)

When you use min-width queries like this ascending order, it is usually referred as Mobile-first structure, because the CSS code you write outside of media queries is for mobile - lowest resolution.

You can also write this in reverse - Desktop-frist structure - using max-width:

```
.menu { /* Desktop - Anything above 1440 */
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 5%;
}

@media (max-width: 1440px) { /* Tablet - 1440 to 640 */
    .menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10%;
        left: 2%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 640px) { /* Mobile - Anything below 640 */
    .menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation. As viks said above bootstrap can help clean up all the media queries so ill definitely be taking a good look at that.